# table caption and footnote not sideways when applying adjustbox

Tags: tables, longtable, rotating, pdflscape, lscape

I have the following table, I want to make it a sideways table, however when I do so the table caption does not go sideways, also the table footnotes do not go "sideways".

That is, I am trying to get the footnote to be a table footnote and also make the table caption sit on top of the table.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
\title{Some title}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage{graphicx} %Loading the package
\graphicspath{{graphics/}} %Setting the graphicspath
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section(Section with table in)

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\small
\captionof{table}{Word2Vec Company Similarities}
\label{tab:Word2Vec_Company_Word_Similarities} 
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\begin{tabular}{||c| c c| c c| c c| c c||} 
 \hline
 Word Input & Most Similar & 2006 & Most Similar & 2010 & Most Similar & 2014 & Most Similar & 2018 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
%%%%%%% Row 1 %%%%%%%%%
text          & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044\footnote{some text here} \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248} \\


\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

EDIT:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}     % Move adjustbox here
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\small
\captionof{table}{Word2Vec Company Similarities}
\label{tab:Word2Vec_Company_Word_Similarities} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{||c| c c| c c| c c| c c||} 
 \hline
 Word Input & Most Similar & 2006 & Most Similar & 2010 & Most Similar & 2014 & Most Similar & 2018 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
%%%%%%% Row 1 %%%%%%%%%
text          & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044\footnote{some text here} \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248} \\

%%%%%%% Row 2 %%%%%%%%%
text          & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044\footnote{some text here} \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248} \\

%%%%%%% Row 3 %%%%%%%%%
text          & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044\footnote{some text here} \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248} \\

%%%%%%% Row 4 %%%%%%%%%
text          & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044\footnote{some text here} \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248} \\



%%%%%%% Row 5 %%%%%%%%%
text          & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044\footnote{some text here} \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248} \\

%%%%%%% Row 6 %%%%%%%%%
text          & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044\footnote{some text here} \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248} \\

%%%%%%% Row 7 %%%%%%%%%
text          & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044\footnote{some text here} \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248} \\

%%%%%%% Row 8 %%%%%%%%%
text          & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044\footnote{some text here} \\  248}

              & \makecell{text \\  text  \\  text  \\  text  \\  text }
              & \makecell{12 \\  45 \\  54 \\  044 \\  248} \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustbox}   % Move adjustbox here
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: you could use the `sidewaystable` environment from `rotating` package. or just put the whole of the `minipage` in your `adjustbox` not just the `tabular`

Comment: Thanks! This works, however the table falls off the page

Comment: well given that you have not provided a test document, so we have no idea how big your page is, or what fonts or size your table is, there is not much that can be said about that other than stick `\small` at the start of the minipage or `\footnotesize` or whatever works

Comment: Apologies, didn't realise I had to submit a document template. The document I am using is an A4 document. Will add a template now

Comment: But as posted it does not work, it uses several undefined commands

Comment: I added all of the packages I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an updated MWE. I suggest using the package [pdflscape](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) to turn tables sideways. They will start on a new page, of cause. In addition, I suggest using [threeparttablex](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttablex), so you can have both multipage tables, table notes and captions without problem. The package use [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) to typeset the tables. In addition, I have used [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for rules, and grouped rows by adding some space. As you will see, I have used [multirow](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) to centre the text in the first column, instead of putting the content of one row in a in a makecell-commands.

If you accept that the tablenotes intervene with ordinary footnotes, you can use longtable's own footnotes. They will be typeset at the bottom of the page, i.e. in the right margin, and is not accumulated on the last page of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption, threeparttablex, booktabs, multirow, pdflscape, longtable}

\begin{document}
\title{Some title}   %% <======== Title here
\maketitle

\section{Section with table in}

Some highflying, not understandable theories here.

\begin{landscape}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft,para]
\item[a] Tablenotes are typeset 
\item[b] at the bottom of the last page of the table.
\item[c] some text here
\item[d] some text here
\item[e] some text here
\item[f] some text here
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{@{}l*{4}{cr}@{}} 
\toprule
 Word Input & Most Similar & 2006 & Most Similar & 2010 & Most Similar & 2014 & Most Similar & 2018 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textit{continued}}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
% the contents of the table
        & text & 12 & text & 12 & text\footnote{Where is my footnote?} & 12 & text & 12 \\
        & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45\\
             & text & 54 & text & 54 & text & 54 & text & 54\\
            & text & 044 & text & 044 & text & 044\tnote{a} & text & 044 \\
\multirow{-5}{*}{text} & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 \\
\addlinespace
        & text & 12 & text & 12 & text & 12 & text & 12 \\
        & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45\\
             & text & 54 & text & 54 & text\footnote{In the right margin} & 54 & text & 54\\
            & text & 044 & text & 044 & text & 044\tnote{b} & text & 044 \\
\multirow{-5}{*}{text} & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 \\
\addlinespace
        & text & 12 & text & 12 & text & 12 & text & 12 \\
        & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45\\
             & text & 54 & text & 54 & text & 54 & text & 54\\
            & text & 044 & text & 044 & text & 044\tnote{c} & text & 044 \\
\multirow{-5}{*}{text} & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 \\
\addlinespace
        & text & 12 & text & 12 & text & 12 & text & 12 \\
        & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45\\
             & text & 54 & text & 54 & text & 54 & text & 54\\
            & text & 044 & text & 044 & text & 044\tnote{d} & text & 044 \\
\multirow{-5}{*}{text} & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 \\
\addlinespace
        & text & 12 & text & 12 & text & 12 & text & 12 \\
        & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45\\
             & text & 54 & text & 54 & text & 54 & text & 54\\
            & text & 044 & text & 044 & text & 044\tnote{e} & text & 044 \\
\multirow{-5}{*}{text} & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 \\
\addlinespace
        & text & 12 & text & 12 & text & 12 & text & 12 \\
        & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45 & text & 45\\
             & text & 54 & text & 54 & text & 54 & text & 54\\
            & text & 044 & text & 044 & text & 044\tnote{f} & text & 044 \\
\multirow{-5}{*}{text} & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 & text & 248 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! but when I add more rows to the table, it "falls" off the page.

Comment: @user113156 If you add more than a page of rows, then you need to use longtable instead. Sideways longtable with tablenotes is a special case. You cannot put a longtable in a minipage, or some other nonbreaking environment.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help! I will look into this. On your plot (and on mine) the table isn't centered - do you have a link to something that can tell me how to center sideways tables?

Comment: @user113156 I have updated the example